# Why is .next() method not working here, jQuery?

Tags: jquery

So I have a form that's half built here.

I have 10 lines, I don't want the next line to be available until there is something in the current line.

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/likwid_t/Mjx7U/4/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var openLines = $('.lineToText');
    if (openLines.length){
        //$('textarea').css('display', 'none');
        openLines.each(function(index, element){
            if (index>0) {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        $('.lineToText').on('keyup', this, function(){
            if (this.value.length){
                $(this).next('.lineToText').prop('disabled', false); //<== thought this would do the job but it's not
                } else {
                    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                    }
            });
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<TABLE SUMMARY="layout table" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">

<TR>

<TD  VALIGN="TOP"><INPUT ID="Q1_96" ONCLICK="ExclusiveChoiceClick('Q1:96');" ONKEYPRESS="return true;" TABINDEX="100" TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="Q1:96" VALUE="96" ></TD><TD  CLASS="CHOICES" VALIGN="TOP"  >1: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

2: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

3: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

4: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

5: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

6: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

7: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

8: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

9: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><br>

10: <INPUT class="lineToText" type="text" size="50"><BR><TEXTAREA  ID="Q1_96_O" TABINDEX="101" COLS="25" ROWS="5" CLASS="OPENENDEDANSWER" NAME="Q1:O"></TEXTAREA></TD>

</TR>

<TR>

<TD  VALIGN="TOP"><INPUT ID="Q1_99" ONCLICK="ExclusiveChoiceClick('Q1:99');" ONKEYPRESS="return true;" TABINDEX="102" TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="Q1:99" VALUE="99" ></TD><TD  CLASS="CHOICES" VALIGN="TOP">Don't Know</TD>

</TR>

</TABLE>
```

Thought $(this).next('.lineToText') would be appropriate to select the next item but it doesn't, can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From [**jQuery Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/next/):*

**Description:** Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Use [`nextAll(".lineToText:first")`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead.

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mjx7U/6/)

The reason your approach doesn't work is because of the `<br />` elements that are in between your `<input />`elements.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try this:

```
if (this.value.length > 0) {
    $(this).siblings('.lineToText').first().removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Comment: Answer above worked, this.value.length return a number, no if there isn't anything I'll get 0 (false) and if there is something I'll get a positive number (true)